# Create a PIN looking box for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create a PIN page for a Windows Phone 8.1 application with only numbers for the users of my app, to access some sensitive info. I used a passwordBox but it doesn't have the InputScope for only number, like a TextBox.
![enter image description here][1]
. Does anybody happened to implement some same functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `InputScope` for `PasswordBox`, as you would for `TextBox`. You have to create your own control. I have one at https://github.com/igorkulman/NumericPasswordBox.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast and amazing answer.

Comment: Because I am new to Windows Phone Development, can you help with how I refer to the custom control. Please see my updated question if you want to help. Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank a lot again.